# Javascript event for when a value is changed via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, webkit

So I know several varieties of this question have been asked in the past but I just want to see if anything has changed with html5 and everything.

Basically, I have web based forms that have events for when they change. (Via onchange, onclick, ect). Now these forms actually store their values in a javascript variable. I realize how I am doing this is different and I could just be checking the fields at a later time for the changes. However, because of the application I am building, having the immediate events is necessarily.

The problem I am having is that things like password managers (and I am assuming plugins like roboform) change the values of the form fields via javascript. When javascript changes these values, it doesn't fire the events that I am currently using.

Now I know that IE has a proprietary function called "propertychange". Firefox also has a similar function called "DOMAttrModified" (which I believe also is kind of supported in IE9 now). Each of these, I believe, would work because I could actively watch the value of the field and this event would be fired when javascript changes the value. However, both chrome and safari don't seem to have a similar function.

My main question is if I am missing anything that would allow this to work in chrome and safari (without using settimeout)? Also, is there going to be a way to do this in HTML5? It seems a little silly to me that there isn't a standard way to do this.

Lastly, is it possible to instead STOP things like lastpass from actually filling in your fields. I know you can put autocomplete="off" and they are supposed to not actually fill in those fields but that doesn't seem to be working with lastpass.

Comment: I had to read trough to the fourth paragraph to figure out that you're asking for a cross-browser propertychange/DOMAttrModified implementation. You could have mentioned that earlier (in the title?)...

Comment: Well that isn't the only thing I am looking for. If there is an event instead to grab when javascript changes a value then I am looking for that as well. I feel my title explains exactly what I am wanting though.

Comment: Are you only interested in `value` properties of from-field DOM elements, or do you need a solution that works on any property of any object?

Comment: @Vidas I only am concerned with the value property. popertychange/DOMAttrModified are the only methods that I actually have found that can do that though. Now, this gets more complicated when it comes to select boxes but I am not as concerned about these because I believe I have other work arounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Safari and Chrome [support](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/#t18) DOMSubtreeModified, you can listen for it and then check for the specific attribute if the DOM subtree of the element doesn't get much changes otherwise.

Alternatively, you might try using Javascript setters (via [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this and it does appear to work when you change the actual HTML or add nodes or remove nodes. (Awesome, have always wondered if it was possible to do those!) However, it doesn't appear to work when you actually change the value of an input box.

Comment: @pierce71588: how about using setters?

Comment: @Tgr well the problem is that things like "lastpass" are actually doing the work, not me. So I can't really control how they change the value on the page. I don't have to have "lastpass" work even. The biggest issue is it shows up on the form, but it isn't actually there since my javascript hasn't ran.

Comment: You can control how the node reacts, though, with something like `Object.defineProperty(passwordField, 'value', {set: function(val) {this.innerHTML = val; console.log(val);}});`. I'm not saying it's a good solution, but as a desperation move, it might work.

Comment: @Tgr well I am cautiously optimistic. This "appears" to actually catch it when I change the value in both firefox 4 and chrome. IE doesn't work but there are other options for IE. Do you know by chance what versions this works for? Now I just need to do some more research into what this is actually doing because it appears that it is making the value attribute inaccessible through normal means.

Comment: I now see why you said it isn't a "good solution" since it is replacing the actual input. So that is problematic since you can't change the value of the field. This gives me a direction to look into though! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @pierce71588: you have to set the value yourself in the setter. Done naively, this would result in infinite recursion, which is why I use `innerHTML` and not value in the setter for `value`; a more robust solution might be to disable the setter, set, then re-enable it. This is still a very brittle solution, so in production I would probably prefer polling the field for changes every 100ms or so.

Comment: @Tgr Ya I noticed the infinite recursion. I set the innerHTML but it doesn't appear to actually set the "display value" of the input box. It actually appears like the input box is broken as soon as you do this. However, I do see ways that you could probably make this work and be less brittle. It would require being built from the ground up though. Thanks for the help! It really confuses me that even with html5 there isn't a better way to handle this kind of thing. Seems like a key "binding" concept that really is being forgotten.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox has a non-standard `Object.watch()` method that allows you to know when a property is changed from JavaScript - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch. From all I know, no other browsers chose to implement it because of performance implications.

For Chrome you are out of luck I think - they even chose to not implement DOM mutation events to get a better performance score. You can only resort to polling there - e.g. check the value every 100 milliseconds to see whether it changed. Safari supports `DOMAttrModified` but it might not fire in this scenario (depends on whether the password manager actually changes the attribute or only the property).

Comment: Thanks that is good to know about. Unfortunately, chrome and safari are the ones that I need a solution for.

Comment: @pierce71588: I revised my answer to add a paragraph on Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this (plain JS)

```
<script>

var tId=[];

window.onload=function() {
  var inputs =document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i=0, n=inputs.length;i<n;i++) {
    if (inputs[i].className.indexOf("watch") !=1) {
      inputs[i].onfocus=function() {
        var id = this.id;
        tId[id]=setInterval(
          function(){ 
            var fld = document.getElementById(id);
            if (fld.value!=fld.defaultValue) fld.onchange() 
          },100);
      }      
      inputs[i].onblur=function() {
        var id = this.id;
        clearInterval(tId[id])
      }      
    }
  }
}


</script>
<form id="form1">
<input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" value="" class="watch"/>
</form>
```